# Evaluating a limit without L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The problem at hand:

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{4^x-4}{2^x-2}=?$$

I know this problem could be easily done with L'Hopital's rule but I was wondering what the optimal solution would be to get rid of the discontinuity at $x=1$ without invoking the rule? I tried all sorts of algebraic manipulations to no avail so any input would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Please use Mathjax. I edited the post for you.

Comment: Thank you! I usually do the typesetting myself but I was short on time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HINT**

Use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ that is

$$4^x-4=2^{2x}-2^2=(2^x-2)(2^x+2)$$